# Why my installation of Wireshark cannot analyze RTP protocol?

Tags: networking, streaming, wireshark, rtp

I am using wireshark 3.2.4 on Windows10, to capture a rtp over TCP/UDP stream to do analyze,
but the protocol column shows no RTP data.

So I searched the web, and see an article [about RTP in wireshark](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP), then I downloaded the the SampleCaptures file [rtp_example.raw.gz](https://wiki.wireshark.org/SampleCaptures?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=rtp_example.raw.gz) and open in wireshark, but different from [the screenshot in the article](https://wiki.wireshark.org/RTP?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=RTPframe.gif), where there are RTP and h.245, here is [my screenshot of opening rtp_example.raw.gz](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nii3W.png), so what should I do to get the similar analyse results as the article shows? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Wireshark can't find the right dissector for a package by itsself you can tell it how to interpret the received packages:

1. Select in your capture one of the lines that represents a package that you think is part of the RTP stream. It probably has protocol UDP.
2. Select 'Decode as...' from the Analyze menu, or by right-clicking
3. Select the line that represents your stream and set the value for 'Current' to 'RTP'. Click OK.

In your capture you will now see that packages from that stream are interpreted as RTP.

More info in the [Wireshark help docs](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChCustProtocolDissectionSection.html).

Comment: Thanks for your precise instruction, may I ask if it's normal that Wireshark can't find the right dissector? And should I dig into the Wireshark doc to learn all the details?

Comment: As far as I know Wireshark tries to guess the protocol. By looking at the source and destination port e.g. but also by others means I don't know. Digging in the docs will certainly help you in understanding Wireshark better. But that is up to you.