# SIP protocol do not display in wireshark when doing phone call by using linphone

Tags: wireshark, sip, voip

I am using linphone to do a voice all between two computers. And I tried to analyze the SIP packet through wireshark but it did not displayed any. I filtred by using the address ip of the other PC. I got UDP, STUN protocols, but always no sip. How can I set correctly set the wireshark or linphone to show the SIP packets?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Find out which port LinPhone uses for SIP. Probably 5060. And then check in Wireshark for packets sent to that port.

If LinPhone doesn't use 5060 it might be that Wireshark doesn't recognize the SIP packets and you have tell Wireshark how to decode them, See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62038236/why-my-installation-of-wireshark-cannot-analyze-rtp-protocol/62040093#62040093), but use 'Decode as SIP'.

Comment: In the linphone, the port of SIP is 5060 by default and I didn't change it. But in the wireshark, when I filtre by udp.port==5060 or tcp.port==5060, I got no packets. I only have STUN and UDP port 52897 packets, and I tried to decode the UDP packets as SIP. Nothing changed... I have no idea what goes wrong..

Comment: Are you capturing the right interface with Wireshark? I'm assuming you can successfully setup a call using LinPhone and you run Wireshark on the same computer. You should see a change in activity in Wireshark when the call becomes active. That's because of the RTP packets being sent/received. Look for those in the capture. The SIP Invite messages can be found right before the first RTP packets are captured. Work your way from there.

Comment: Hi Bucq, I am running a call using LinPhone and Wireshark on the same computer. I can see the RTP packets by decoding the udp.port 7078 which is the audio rtp port used by Linphone. But right before the RTP packets, I got STUN packets instead of SIP. Any ideas how could I see the SIP?

Comment: And I noticed that the sip port 5060 is never been used. But port 7078 have STUN and RTP packets when I run the call.

Comment: You could check which process is using port 5060. Maybe another process than LinPhone bound to that port first and LinPhone uses another port. Start your command prompt with elevated (admin) rights and type 'netstat -vanbt'.
Sending/receiving STUN from/on your RTP port is completely normal.